# show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{1}{x^k}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, infinity

I am reading Calculus, Purcell and there is a solved example

Show that if $k$ a positive integer, then

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^k}=0\ \text{ and} \ \lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{1}{x^k}=0$$
The first part was proven in the book by taking $M=\sqrt[k]{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}$, then $x>M$ implies that
$$|\frac{1}{x^k}-0|=\frac{1}{x^k}<\frac{1}{M^k}=\epsilon.$$

For the second statement, the book states that the proof is similar. However, we assume that $x<M$. Therefore,
$$|\frac{1}{x^k}-0|=\frac{1}{x^k}>\frac{1}{M^k}=\epsilon.$$

which is not what we want. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to consider $x<-M$, in which case you have $|x|>M$, hence $$\left|\frac1{x^k}-0\right|=\frac1{|x|^k}<\frac1{M^k}.$$

Comment: In general, you can show that $~f(x) \to 0,~$ by showing that $~|~f(x)~| \to 0.$